# SignalR C# client can't receive messages, but a Javascript client can

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have a C# .NET SignalR Hub running on Windows which I've been testing with a Javascript client.  This works, but I am having problems getting the equivalent C# client to receive messages.

The Hub uses websockets and rejects connections that don't have the websocket Upgrade header.  It uses HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.  One of the hub methods is a basic connectivity check that echoes a simple text test message back to the client, roughly similar to the ChatHub AspNetCore demo app from GitHub.  The message is plain text rather than JSON.

The Javascript client connects, sends and receives messages OK.  This works whether the server is hosted within Visual Studio or with IIS on Windows Server 2019.

The C# client connects OK over HTTPS (discarding certificate checks due to the self-signed certificate), and the connection State is Connected.  It sends the test message, which can be seen arriving in the server logs, but the C# client doesn't receive the echoed response.  There are no exceptions on the client or server side.  It looks as if I have mistyped the method name, but I don't think I have.

I will paste both the Javascript Invoke and the C# InvokeAsync for comparison.  Thanks in advance to anyone that can point me in the right direction!

Javascript SignalR client code - works as expected:

```
connection.on("TestMessage", function (msg)
{
    logMsg("TestMessage: " + msg);
});
```

---

C# equivalent.  This is setup before calling hubConnection.StartAsync().  However, the handler is never called.

```
this.hubConnection.On<string, string>("TestMessage", (user, message) =>
{
    var newMessage = $"{user}: {message}";
    this.Log(newMessage);
});
```

Comment: That's not equivalent. The Javascript method accepts a single arg "msg", the C# client accepts two args "user, message".

Comment: Of course! Thank you for pointing out my mental block in seeing the obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

On Javascript, you are passing only single argument - 'msg', but in C# there are two arguments - 'user, message'.